# How can I block or redirect traffic referred to my site by another site?

Tags: .htaccess, referrer, mod-security

I have a domain that is being sent traffic from another domain with a similar name by a scammer who is trying to look legitimate.  (the scammer is masquerading as my legitimate client)

How can I block or redirect traffic referred to my site by another site?

i.e. any traffic that is referred from IP address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx should be either denied or more appropriately referred to a disclaimer page.

I've tried .htaccess mod_rewrite rules, but the apache logs don't show the referring ip address. that only appears in the "general" section of the headers when examined using chrome developer tools.

can this be done using .htaccess or mod_security

Comment: http refers only contain urls, which means there's no IP, unless the browser was literally showing a page with the address `http://127.0.0.1`-type thing. You'd have to parse the referer, do a dns lookup on any hostname found, and then block based on that. and since referers cannot be relied on, you cannot 100% reliably tell when someone did come from that spam site.

Comment: Do you know IP addresses of the scammer hitting your website?

Comment: The referring IP address never appears appears anywhere.  users are requesting domain1.com directly (they are not following a link, so no referrer) , getting a 301 moved permanently then being redirected to domain2.com

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of methods you can use, **IF** you know the IP address you can use:

`deny from xxx.xxx.x.xx`

However, you can actually block directly from a referring website using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

This will display a **403forbidden** message if anyone is redirected via the scammers website.

Comment: there is no referrer. the browser is following a 301 moved permanently.